# Locking mechanism for shell scripts

Tags: shell

Hi I have a shell script which calls another script and I have locking mechanism inside main script.
Please check below code.
Does this mean that other script(/home/user/anotherscript.sh) will not be called and executed as long as script is locked by locking mechanism.

```
function funcexit() {  
     echo "Locked"  
    exit 1  
}
(
    flock -x -w 10 549 || funcexit
       bash /home/user/anotherscript.sh

      do some stuff

)
```

Please let me know the thougts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script line `flock -x -w 10 549 || funcexit` says: "try to get an exlusive lock on fd# 549, with maximum waiting time of 10 seconds, if successfully acquire the lock, continue with the next line, otherwise call function `funcexit` " thus, if the script can not acquire the lock in 10 seconds, `funcexit` will be called (thus exit).